# Get requested user windows login credentials

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows

We are working in a web application in which we need the requested user windows login credentials.
Is there any way to take the requested user windows login username and password. We are working with c#.net.

Comment: You want to retrieve a user's Windows username and password from a web app?

Comment: @Michael: yes , is it possible?

Comment: It is only possible if you are using integrated security

Comment: Your server would need to know how do do NTLM authentication, I'm sure it is possible.

Comment: @Ryan: can you please elaborate, sorry i didn't understand

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to get the password. But if it is using Windows Authentication, and an intranet application, then you can use `User.Identity.Name`